# почему таймер не отключается предыдущий, когда включается новый?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Таймер отключается только когда выходит время, а если нажать кнопку то запустится уже новый таймер, и предыдущий тоже будет работать

```js
$(".next").click(function () {
  const secondsToAnswer = 10; // Количество секунд для ответа
  let timeLeft = secondsToAnswer;
  var startTimer = function(){
          const timer = setInterval(function(){
              if (timeLeft > 0) { // На последней секунде
                $('.timer').text(timeLeft + ' сек');
                timeLeft--;
              } else {
                $('.timer').text(0 + ' сек');
                clearInterval(timer);
                $('#next').click();
              }
            }, 1000);
            return timer;
      }
      
      //запуск таймера
      startTimer();
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Потому что при каждом вызове у вас создаётся новая переменная timer, создаётся новая функция которая присваивается ей и с setInterval происходит совершенно аналогичная история.

Для большего понимания почитайте про [замыкания](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures)

Для данной ситуации, решением может быть такое:

```js
$(".next").click(function() {
    const secondsToAnswer = 10; // Количество секунд для ответа
    let timeLeft = secondsToAnswer;
    clearInterval(this.timer);
    this.timer = setInterval(function() {
        if (timeLeft > 0) { // На последней секунде
            $('.timer').text(timeLeft + ' сек');
            timeLeft--;
        } else {
            $('.timer').text(0 + ' сек');
            $('#next').click();
        }
    }, 1000);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="timer">0</div>
<button class="next">next</button>
```

Comment: `$('#next').click();` можно заменить на `clearInterval( $(".next")[0].timer )` — т.к. клик может иметь другие побочные эффекты) Или сохранить this.timer во внешней переменной...

Comment: что то ничего оно не работает

Comment: @Junior, что именно не работает? Добавил пример выполнения в ответ. Могу предположить, что у вас есть проблема с тем, что вы `click` вешаете на селектор по классу `$('.next')`, а после пытаетесь кликнуть по id `$('#next')`

Comment: спасибо у вас работает, почему у меня нужно искать,
у меня получается в hidden блоке загружаются все ответы, потом я каждый клонирую и заменяю в блоке